# 3D Models and Images won't load: webpack and model-viewer

Tags: javascript, webpack, three.js

I'm working on a web-AR project using webpack, but I'm encountering an issue where images and models won't load and result in 404 errors. I've shared my project config and code below. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMLYA.jpg)
[Project Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5FL1.png)

Index.js

```
import { ModelViewerElement } from "@google/model-viewer";
import style from '../assets/css/style.css';
import { Models } from "./ModelManager";


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const modelViewer = document.getElementById('model-viewer-container');
    // console.log(ModelViewerElement);
    modelViewer.setAttribute('src', Models.assets[0].path);
    modelViewer.setAttribute('alt', 'A 3D model');
    modelViewer.setAttribute('camera-controls', '');
    // document.body.appendChild(modelViewer);
    setButtonBackgrounds();
});

function setButtonBackgrounds() {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides .slide');

    slides.forEach(slide => {
        const modelName = slide.getAttribute('data-model');
        const model = Models.assets.find(m => m.name === modelName);
        if (model) {
            slide.style.backgroundImage = `url('${model.thumbnail}')`;
        }
    });
}
```

base.js (Webpack config)

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@webpack': path.resolve(__dirname, 'webpack'),
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg/,
                type: 'assets'
            },
            {
                test: [/\.vert$/, /\.frag$/],
                use: "raw-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|bin|gif|glb|gltf)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    outputPath: '/assets/images'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            root: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['build']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html",
            favicon: 'assets/images/favicon.ico',
            title: "Web AR - Extramarks"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "assets/css/style.css"
        })
    ]
};
```

When i am loading a single model by giving it's path in webpack's module rules, it's working but i want to load multiple models and images at run time but it is not working.

```
{
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|bin|gif|glb|gltf)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        outputPath: '/assets/images',
        name: 'motor.png'
    }
}
```